# Can someone please explain why the output of this question is the list in reverse order?

Tags: python

```
def mystery(l):
    if l == []:
        return(l)
    else:
        return(mystery(l[1:])+l[:1])
mystery([22,14,19,65,82,55])

#output: [55, 82, 65, 19, 14, 22]
```

Please explain how this code is working.
I am not able to understand the recursion part here.

Comment: You should either run the code through a [debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) or throw in some `print` statements and watch what it is doing step-by-step.

Comment: Please share what you _do_ understand about the code

Comment: Have you tried following the code on [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done by list slicing. By returning

```
mystery(I[1:]) + I[:1]
```

you just keep going recursive and adding the first element from the list leftover.

for example:

```
mystery([1,2,3]) -> return mystery([2,3]) + [1] -> return mystery([3]) + [2] + [1]
```

and so on

Answer (score 2):

The recursive part is the following line:

```
return (mystery(l[1:]) + l[:1])
```

Observe that `l[:1]` (i.e., `l[0:1]`) is the list consisting of the first element of `l` and `l[1:]` (i.e., `l[1:len(l)]`) is the list consisting of the remaining part of `l`.
The `+` concatenates lists.
Thus,

```
mystery([1,2,3,4]) = mystery([2,3,4]) + [1]
                   = mystery([3,4]) + [2] + [1]
                   = mystery([4]) + [3] + [2] + [1]
                   = mystery([]) + [4] + [3] + [2] + [1]
                   = [] + [4] + [3] + [2] + [1]
                   = [4,3,2,1]
```

Therefore, `mystery(l)` is the reverse of `l`. That is,

```
mystery(l) = l[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's follow an example, each line is equivalent to the one after it:

```py
mystery([22,14,19,65,82,55])
mystery([22,14,19,65,82,55][1:]) + [22,14,19,65,82,55][:1]
mystery([14,19,65,82,55]) + [22]
mystery([14,19,65,82,55][1:]) + [14,19,65,82,55][:1] + [22]
mystery([19,65,82,55]) + [14] + [22]
...
mystery([19,65]) + [82] + [55] + [14] + [22]
mystery([19,65][1:]) + [19, 65][:1] + [82] + [55] + [14] + [22]
mystery([65]) + [19] + [82] + [55] + [14] + [22]
mystery([65][1:]) + [65][:1] + [19] + [82] + [55] + [14] + [22]
mystery([]) + [65] + [19] + [82] + [55] + [14] + [22]
[] + [65] + [19] + [82] + [55] + [14] + [22]
[65, 19, 82, 55, 14, 22]
```

If you don't understand what `[:1]` [`1:]` means please read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/14160477).